# Team Foundation Server 2010 and Sharepoint Foundation 2010 Integration Error

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2010

I followed most of the suggestions that I found online but I still got this error when I start integrating TFS and SP

[image]

I dont have firewall thats why it does not make sense, any idea why this is happening.  My settings on Sharepoint Web Applications is

[image]

I also get this error when I create a Sharepoint Page for my project

**Server was unable to process request. ---> TF250029: No user was found within the context of a Web site. Verify that the site does not allow anonymous access.**

but I dont allow anonymous access to my website.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked by removing the anonymous access on IIS to the sharepoint site

Comment: +1 - Saved my bacon.  Don't remember actually enabling it, and it had been working for the last year.  Suddenly, over the last week, this popped up out of nowhere, and I was going around in circles trying to figure out what the BPA was complaining about.